# Getting [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib'] this even passlib is already installed

Tags: fastapi, crypt, cjson, passlib

[image]

cjson not found, falling back to stdlib json
Traceback (most recent call last):

.
.

from Crypto.Hash import HMAC, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto

also,
from passlib.context import CryptContext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib'

Comment: please, see the image for more understanding of the error!